# TinyMCE Menu doesn't get sticky to toolbar

Tags: symfony, menu, tinymce, sticky

Im using TinyMCE on a symfony app. Due to cache I'm not actually sure when this problem started happening, but it is very annoying and I have no clue what can possibly be wrong.

I've tried other TinyMCE versions, other jQuery version and the problem still stands, can anyone help?

When I click on the menus they get sticky to the bottom of the browser and not to the toolbar as they are supposed to.

I believe you might need more information and im happy to give it to you.

TinyMCE version: 4.3.3
jQuery: the one included with TinyMCE
Symfony: 3.1.6
PHP: 5.6.32

Thanks a lot for any help, even suggestions on debug.

[Example menu problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFxUj.png)

Comment: Can you create a simple example page that shows this happening?  There is clearly something messing with the calculations TinyMCE is making for where to show the menu but without seeing running code it will be very difficult to diagnose.  I would also note TinyMCE 4.3 is pretty old - you should update to the latest (4.7.12) to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Actually i can't create an example since this is being used on a private CMS, and taking the tinyMCE from that environment would probably fix it but that wouldn't be a real fix to my problem. I was hoping for some kind of "Oh, that happened to me, I had this plugin, or this css trick". I appreciate your help. I've tested already the latest version.  problem persists :s

Comment: @MichaelFromin https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/DPhaab doesn't work in 5.0 also.